# How to fix table header (thead) using boostrap styling in angular js

Tags: html, css, angularjs, bootstrap-4

I want to fix the theader of my AngularJS webpage using the Boostrap Styling. I've looked for too many solutions but none seems to work properly. Do anybody have a simple approach? Also the problem is when I try to add fix, the width changes and is not the same as the tbody.

I've tried fixing my thead using the solutions form w3schools for fixing the header: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sticky_header

Also I havent got sucess looking at solutions using the AngularJS directives.

This is my code:

```
<table class="table table-responsives table-striped table-hover" ts-wrapper
                        ts-no-data-text="No se encontró nada con ese criterio de búsqueda">
                        <thead id="myHeader" class="sticky: sticky">
                            <tr>
                                <th>Semana</th>
                                <th>Fecha</th>
                                <th>Operador</th>
                                <th>Empresa</th>
                                <th>Unidad</th>
                                <th>Origen</th>
                                <th>Destino</th>
                                <th>Flete (MXN)</th>
                                <th>Opciones</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>

                            <tr ng-repeat="p in viajes" ts-repeat>
                                <td>{{p.data.semana}}</td>
                                <td>{{p.data.fecha | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</td>
                                <td>{{p.data.operador.data.nombre}}</td>
                                <td>{{p.data.empresa}}</td>
                                <td> <strong>Tipo de Unidad:</strong> {{p.data.unidad.data.tipo}} <br>
                                    <strong>Tracto:</strong> {{p.data.unidad.data.tracto.placas}} |
                                    {{p.data.unidad.data.tracto.modelo}} |
                                    {{p.data.unidad.data.tracto.marca}} <br>
                                    <strong>Caja:</strong> {{p.data.unidad.data.caja.placas}} |
                                    {{p.data.unidad.data.caja.modelo}} |
                                    {{p.data.unidad.data.caja.marca}}</td>
                                <td>{{p.data.origen}}</td>
                                <td>{{p.data.destino}}</td>
                                <td>$ {{p.data.flete|number}}</td>

                                <td>
                                    <button class="btn btn-circle btn-assertive" ng-click="editarViaje(p)">
                                        <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    </button>
                                    <!-- <button class="btn btn-circle btn-danger" ng-click="eliminarUsuario(p)">
                                        <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    </button> -->
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

```
CSS: 
/* Module Table */
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

I hope at least to keep my width after adding fix to my table header.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
tbody{
  display:block;
  overflow:auto;
  height:200px;
  width:100%;
}
thead tr{
  display:block;
}
```

By controlling the height of the `tbody` to a fixed 200px (or whatever value you want it to be) and then setting the overflow property I believe this will solve the issue